# How to import font-awesome to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, sass, font-awesome, laravel-mix

How to add font-awesome to laravel project. 
I ran:

```
npm install font-awesome
```

But what is next, how to import it in my `app.scss` what is correct path?
I am trying : 
`@import "/node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";`
But get and error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
@import "/node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

Comment: You might want to use relative path instead of an absolute parth

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome/52436453#52436453

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're pulling a file in from your `node_modules` directory you can use `~` followed  by the path to the file inside `node_modules`:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

---

If you have:

```
mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

Then you will need to copy the files in your `webpack.mix.js` file with something like:

```
mix.copy('./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**', 'public/fonts/font-awesome');
```

And then above the `@import` in your `.scss` file have:

```
$fa-font-path: '/fonts/font-awesome';
```